# Difference between unique_ptr two operations

Tags: c++

Description of the two operations of smart pointers on **c++ primer**:

```
unique_ptr<T,D> u1
```

> Null unique_ptrs that can point to objects of type T.u1 will use a callable obejct of type D to free its pointer.

```
unique_ptr<T,D> u2(d)
```

> u2 points to objects of type T that uses d,which must be an object of type D in place of delete.

The description of the two operations is almost similar, I feel a bit confused, what is the difference between these two operations? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Where is your quote from? What is the context? And if you have two separate "descriptions" then please [edit] your question to actually make them separate.

Comment: And have you tried to read [a `std::unique_ptr` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)?

Comment: The good thing is: if you don't understand it, you probably don't need the whole deleter thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean:

```
std::unique_ptr<T,D> u1(new T);
std::unique_ptr<T,D> u2(new T, d); // d convertible to type D
```

The difference is that the first requires `D` to be *DefaultConstructible* as it default constructs the deleter object to be used when the held object is destroyed. The second does not have the same requirement and how the actual deleter object is constructed depends on the value category of `d`.

Documentation for [`std::unique_ptr::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) goes into much more detail on the requirements for the second form, which are quite intricate. But the gist is that you can expect the deleter to be copy- or move constructed from the argument you pass.

It also has an example:

```
// code copied from cppreference.com

struct D { // deleter
    D() {};
    D(const D&) { std::cout << "D copy ctor\n"; }
    D(D&) { std::cout << "D non-const copy ctor\n";}
    D(D&&) { std::cout << "D move ctor \n"; }
    void operator()(Foo* p) const {
        std::cout << "D is deleting a Foo\n";
        delete p;
    };
};
 
int main()
{
    D d;
    {  // deleter type is not a reference
       std::unique_ptr<Foo, D> up3(new Foo, d); // deleter copied
    }
}
```

```
Foo ctor
D copy ctor <---- this is the difference to the first overload
D is deleting a Foo
~Foo dtor
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case:

```
unique_ptr<T,D> u1
```

a deleter will be constructed from the type `D` using the no argument constructor of `D`. In some way, this will give you a kind of "default" deleter of type `D`.

In the case:

```
unique_ptr<T,D> u2(d)
```

the deleter `d` of type `D` is specified, you can choose the deleter instance. Maybe the type `D` has some variants internalized into its instances, or type `D` does not have a no argument constructor.

First case: you choose the type of the deleter.

Second case: you choose the instance of the deleter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct Foo { // object to manage
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo ctor\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "~Foo dtor\n"; }
};

struct D { // deleter
    std::string msg;
    D() { msg = "removing"; };
    D(std::string m) { msg = m; }
    void operator()(Foo* p) const {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        delete p;
    };
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Foo,D> u1(new Foo);
    D d("deleting");
    std::unique_ptr<Foo,D> u2(new Foo,d);
}
```

would give:

```
Foo ctor
Foo ctor
deleting
~Foo dtor
removing
~Foo dtor
```

Comment: there is no constructor for OPs second case. In your code you have it fixed